# library not found in java.library.path

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm a newbie to JNI, so I was trying this introduction to JNI tutorial earlier that just calls native to print Hello World! Everything went fine until the point that I wanted to run the java file, at which I keep getting the error: Exception in thread "main": java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hello library found in java.library.path. I have googled the error and looked at a lot of peoples' suggestions, but none worked for me unfortunately! I have tried the following:

- Running with command: java -Djava.library.path = "*Path to library*" HelloWorld
- setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my .so path

Everyone else had their issues resolved after doing one of the two above, but not me!

Here is the Java Code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }

    private native void printHelloWorld();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().printHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

And code for native is as follows:

```
void JNICALL Java_printHelloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf("HelloWorld!");
}
```

EDIT: I even tried copying the library to the actually directory of java.library.path, but it's still giving me the same error!

Comment: Please show your full code, for both the native part and the Java part.

Comment: java.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH have to point to _directories_ containing the .so file(s), not the file(s) themselve(s).

Comment: for me, 32 bit jvm gives the same message when the path contains 64 bit libraries...

Answer (score 5):

What is your library called?  If your paths are correct, your library name is probably wrong.  If the library you are loading is called `hello`, on Windows the file needs to be called `hello.dll`, on every other SO you also need to prepend the `lib` prefix:

- on OS X (Java < 1.7) `libhello.jnilib`
- on OS X (Java >= 1.7) `libhello.dylib`
- on just about everything else will be `libhello.so`.

Notice that the Windows dll file is the only file name without the "lib" prefix and that the "lib" prefix is not used when calling `System.loadLibrary("hello")`.
If you are still experiencing a problem loading the lib, try `System.load("/path/to/my/libhello.so")` to try and load the library directly.

You can always check the file the system will look for by running

```
System.mapLibraryName(libName)
```

Comment: hint if someone is using Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks and IntelliJ:

install opencv with homebrew
`$ brew install homebrew/science/opencv --with-java`

add opencv to (global) libraries:
`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/share/OpenCV/java`

edit run configuration (vm option):
`-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/share/OpenCV/java`

Still getting an error like this?
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java249 in java.library.path`

check Java version:
`$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"`

solution: upgrade the Java SDK

Answer (score 2):

@Alex Barker
The version

```
System.load("/path/to/my/libhello.so")
```

does not resolve dependencies. If there are dependencies upon other user-defined libraries, they need to be loaded before.

Comment: use `ldd /path/to/my/libhello.so` to see dependencies

Comment: + On Windows, good old ´Depency Walker´ does the job